# A word that means 'trendy but generic'

Tags: single-word-requests

For example,

> "The bar's decor was a modern, trendy style but felt very generic."

Are there any words that describe a style that is trendy but also quite generic and overly used?

Comment: All your questions seem to be crossword-puzzle types. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Isn't this what *trendy* means on its own?

Comment: ...but felt very bland/samey/mass-produced/cookie-cutter etc. etc.

Comment: @tchrist No, just coincidence I guess. I just want to use the most accurate words as I find describing something as "x but y" sounds kind of awkward.

Comment: off-the-rack trendy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Expert Advice on How Not to Decorate Like a Walking Fashion Cliché
>   http://stylecaster.com/decorating-mistakes/

I would say, "cliché".

Comment: 'Cliché' at least connotes old-fashioned, hackneyed.

Comment: A cliché is anything *but* trendy. A given cliché might have been trendy at one point, before it became a cliché. Something trendy is gaining in popularity, and typically new. Definitely *not* a cliché.